# Uninitialized constant Bandit::Engine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-engines, bandit

I have a Rails 3.2, Ruby 1.9 app that I'm attempting to setup with the [bandit gem](https://github.com/bmuller/bandit).

I've bundled installed the gem, run the `bandit:install` and modified the `bandit.yml` to (for development) values of `round_robin` and `memory`.

However, all attempts to start the dev server (`rails s`) result in the following error:

```
/Users/michaelbuckbee/Sites/bshapp/config/routes.rb:148:in `block in ': uninitialized constant Bandit::Engine (NameError)
    from /Users/michaelbuckbee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@bshapp/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `instance_exec'
    from /Users/michaelbuckbee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@bshapp/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:282:in `eval_block'
    from /Users/michaelbuckbee/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p0@bshapp/gems/actionpack-3.2.12/lib/action_dispatch/routing/route_set.rb:260:in `draw'
    from /Users/michaelbuckbee/Sites/bshapp/config/routes.rb:1:in `'
```

If I remove the `Bandit::Engine` line from the `routes.rb` and go into the rails console I can successfully create Bandit Experiments.

Comment: Could you post the version of routes.rb that produces the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just followed the instructions on the bandit readme and got the same error. The latest tagged version at this time is `bandit-0.1.0`; this is what bundler will install if you don't specify any options with `gem 'bandit'`. I suspect you're using the same version. Looking at the source of that version, `Bandit::Engine` does not exist. It does appear to be included in bandit HEAD, which is on commit 4c552c1efa at this time. Bundling from HEAD fixed the problem for me.

So, add the following in your Gemfile, bundle install, and retry your server:

```
gem 'bandit', :git => "git://github.com/bmuller/bandit.git"
```